# Model Binding falls out of sync in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that I am rewriting to use with a `factory`. One problem I've encountered is a delayed ng-model that updates correctly the first time but then falls out of sync when updated after subsequent API calls.

I've done some digging and found this http://learnwebtutorials.com/why-ng-model-value-should-contain-a-dot as how to fix this delay, to not avail. To avoid an endless if else block, i've indexed my model with strings:

```
var _brands = {
        'brand1': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
        'brand2': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
        'brand3': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
        // ~10 more
    };
```

In it's default state, the model updates well. The problems start if there is already populated data inside the model.

Say I have:

```
var _brands = {
            'brand1': [{ID: '234', location: 'Vermont', isStarred: false, rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            'brand2': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            'brand3': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            // ~10 more
        };
```

And after updating the values client side, the data from the API call comes back as:

```
var _brands = {
            'brand1': [{ rank: '1' }, {ID:'956', location:'Hawaii', isStarred: true, rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            'brand2': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            'brand3': [{ rank: '1' }, { rank: '2' }, { rank: '3' }],
            // ~10 more
        };
```

The first API call updates the model correctly, but any subsequent requests are delayed by one. What in the world is going on? Can anyone explain this process?

factory:

```
var _saveSelection = function (data) {
        api.post('Distributor/UpdateSelection', data).then(function () {
            api.get('Distributor/GetSelections').then(function (brands) {
                angular.copy(_initial, _brands); //This is done to 'reset' the model.
                for (var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++) {
                    _brands[brands[i].brand][brands[i].rank - 1] = brands[i];
                }
                deffered1.resolve(_brands);
            });
        });
        return deffered1.promise;
    };
    var _getSelections = function () {
        api.get('Distributor/GetSelections').then(function (brands) {
            angular.copy(_initial, _brands); //again, I want to reset the model
            for (var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++) {
                _brands[brands[i].brand][brands[i].rank - 1] = brands[i]; 
            }
            deffered2.resolve(_brands);
        });
        return deffered2.promise;
    };
    return {
        saveSelection: function (data) {
            return _saveSelection(data);
        },
        getSelections: function () {
            return _getSelections();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was copying the object to itself in the Controller:

```
 brandsService.saveSelection(data).then(
                    function (brand) {
                        angular.copy(brand, $scope.brand); //Here
                        $scope.closeDistributorSelection();
                    },
                    function () {
                        //handle error
                    });
```

I was unaware that the factory was already writing to my $scope. Apologies!

Fixed Code:

```
 brandsService.saveSelection(data).then(
                        function (brand) {
                               $scope.closeDistributorSelection();
                        },
                        function () {
                            //handle error
                        });
```